# Collapsed navbar is covering content behind it in bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, transparent

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4. I need the background of the links in the navbar (once it has collapsed at the breakpoint) to be about 50% transparent so that it's not covering the content behind it. Right now, when I click on "Menu" a big block with the links vertically stacked comes down and covers anything that's behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once bootstrap reaches 768 pixels the navigation bar collapses and shows an icon to the right of the navigation bar which allows a dropdown menu to display vertically. Now, to change the dropdown menu not to be opaque and see the background 50% transparent the following code can be added to your custom.css.

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: { your choice of color };
        opacity:0.5;
    }
}
```

...or if you just want to see just the background behind the text and nothing else, apply the code to the custom.css as...

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .navbar-inverse {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        opacity:0.5;
    }
}
```